# No property XXX for type String! in JPA derived query with set from composite primary key item

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with JPA derived Queries in a repository for which I use two items of a composite Primary Key that I defined with @EmbededId. The main difficulty is that I try to use a set of string of one item of the Primary Key and at runtime, I get the following error:

> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void ca.hydro.publication.repository.PublicationChangementDateRepository.deleteBychangementDatePKSourceAndchangementDatePKNoPaIn(java.lang.String,java.util.List)! No property andchangementDatePKNoPa found for type String! Traversed path: ChangementDate.changementDatePK.source.**
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
> Blockquote
>
> **Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property andchangementDatePKNoPa found for type String! Traversed
> path: ChangementDate.changementDatePK.source.**   at
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:381)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:1.8.0_192]   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:382)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:97)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]    ... 73 common
> frames omitted
> Blockquote

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it's a simple mistake that I made but I don't see anything wrong... :-(

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHANGEMENT_DATE", catalog="rapports", schema="dbo")
public class ChangementDate  {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChangementDatePK changementDatePK;
    
    private Date valeurDate;
    private String projectUID;
    private UUID extractionUID;
    private LocalDateTime dateExtraction;
    private String typeAction;
    private LocalDateTime dateAction;
    private String ancienNomMes;
    private String noTacheMes;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator" , strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "EXTRACTION_UID" , columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")    
    public UUID getExtractionUID() {
        return extractionUID;
    }

    @Column(name="VALEUR_DATE")
    public Date getValeurDate() {
        return valeurDate;
    }
    
    @Column(name="PROJECTUID")
    public String getProjectUID() {
        return projectUID;
    }

    @Column(name="DATE_EXTRACTION")
    public LocalDateTime getDateExtraction() {
        return dateExtraction;
    }

    @Column(name="TYPE_ACTION")
    public String getTypeAction() {
        return typeAction;
    }
    
    @Column(name="DATE_ACTION")
    public LocalDateTime getDateAction() {
        return dateAction;
    }
    
    @Column(name="ANCIEN_NOM_MES")
    public String getAncienNomMes() {
        return ancienNomMes;
    }
    
    @Column(name="NO_TACHE_MES")
    public String getNoTacheMes() {
        return noTacheMes;
    }

    
    public ChangementDate(){
        super();
    }

    public void setExtractionUID(UUID extractionUID) {
        this.extractionUID = extractionUID;
    }

    public ChangementDatePK getChangementDatePK() {
        return changementDatePK;
    }

    public void setChangementDatePK(ChangementDatePK changementDatePK) {
        this.changementDatePK = changementDatePK;
    }

    public void setValeurDate(Date valeurDate) {
        this.valeurDate = valeurDate;
    }

    public void setProjectUID(String projectUID) {
        this.projectUID = projectUID;
    }

    public void setDateExtraction(LocalDateTime dateExtraction) {
        this.dateExtraction = dateExtraction;
    }

    public void setTypeAction(String typeAction) {
        this.typeAction = typeAction;
    }

    public void setDateAction(LocalDateTime dateAction) {
        this.dateAction = dateAction;
    }

    public void setAncienNomMes(String ancienNomMes) {
        this.ancienNomMes = ancienNomMes;
    }

    public void setNoTacheMes(String noTacheMes) {
        this.noTacheMes = noTacheMes;
    }
}
```

Embeddable Entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class ChangementDatePK implements Serializable {
    
    @Column(name="SOURCE")
    protected String source;
    
    @Column(name="NO_PA")
    protected String noPa;
    
    @Column(name="CODE_ARRIMAGE")
    protected String codeArrimage;
    
    @Column(name="TYPE_DATE")
    protected String typeDate;
    
    
    public ChangementDatePK() {
        
    }
    
    public ChangementDatePK(String source, String noPa, String codeArrimage, String typeDate) {
        
        this.source = source;
        this.noPa = noPa;
        this.codeArrimage = codeArrimage;
        this.typeDate = typeDate;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getNoPa() {
        return noPa;
    }

    public void setNoPa(String noPa) {
        this.noPa = noPa;
    }

    public String getCodeArrimage() {
        return codeArrimage;
    }

    public void setCodeArrimage(String codeArrimage) {
        this.codeArrimage = codeArrimage;
    }

    public String getTypeDate() {
        return typeDate;
    }

    public void setTypeDate(String typeDate) {
        this.typeDate = typeDate;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ChangementDatePK)) return false;
        ChangementDatePK that = (ChangementDatePK) o;
        return Objects.equals(getSource(), that.getSource()) &&
                Objects.equals(getNoPa(), that.getNoPa()) &&
                Objects.equals(getCodeArrimage(), that.getCodeArrimage()) &&
                Objects.equals(getTypeDate(), that.getTypeDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getSource(), getNoPa(), getCodeArrimage(), getTypeDate());
    }   
}
```

Repository:
You can see in the code below that I try to call derived Query using the Items of my composite primary key.  The items are "Source" and "noPa".  But I try to find or delete rows that have specific "source" for all "noPa" of my Set passed as parameter.

```
@Repository
public interface PublicationChangementDateRepository extends JpaRepository<ChangementDate, ChangementDatePK>{
    
    List<ChangementDate> findBychangementDatePKSourceAndchangementDatePKNoPaIn(String source, Set<String> noPa);
    
    void deleteBychangementDatePKSourceAndchangementDatePKNoPaIn(String source, Set<String> noPa);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your responses!

Comment: Your capitalization is inconsistent. (And I'll note that by the time your method names are _that_ complex, it's a sign it's time to go ahead and write a query or at least a default-method alias.)

Comment: You're right. writing a query was my next idea... I never tried a default-method-alias though.  I'll check that out.  Thanks for the reply!